# Directly accessing a video

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

In learning more about web scraping, I'm attempting to directly access the video file here http://video.disney.com/watch/disneychannel-no-service-4df889ed3d82b43c9c01a272

What is the direct the link? And how did you derive it?

UPDATE : after following the answer below the URL is http://cdn.videos.dolimg.com/channel_shortform/unknown/i29083/869089-tpr_hi29083_gdj-h264m_aac_848x480_904x96.mp4

The inspector gives me the following 'Query String Parameters'.

```
app:w88_dolwa_prod02
trckTp:trackvideo
vendorLst:c,n,o
lSwid:AA50B128-8C31-4B59-A487-019721763B4A
pgVwId:cto-1372188161916-8691154154948
fullPgNm:dcom|dch|watch:disneychannel-no-service-4df889ed3d82b43c9c01a272|disneychannel-no-service-4df889ed3d82b43c9c01a272
arPgNm:na
plgId:7173e513b73b5ca23f3b93fbb4664f0be83c0df8
ua:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
res:1440x900
cod:32
eventLst:e1,e73,e68
categoryCd:dcom
siteCd:dch
brdcrums:watch:disneychannel-no-service-4df889ed3d82b43c9c01a272
buId:4b90600fa5ba550f422a8ba2
propId:4bdfd35102a87496bbe03d00
buCd:dch
mstCd:mic
templateTp:watch
ASSETID:0_y1nplyhi
KSESSIONID:4ca7bebd-9389-893f-ed7a-de46a7d4928c
KSESSIONSEQ:1
KDPEVNT:percentReached
KDPDAT_VALUE:0
KDPDAT_PLAYHEAD:0
ASSETNAME:vid|dch|dmms|shr|0_y1nplyhi|No Service
AUTO:true
KDPPROTO:Flash
assetNm:vid|dch|dmms|shr|0_y1nplyhi|no service
adPgNm:/7046/dch/mickey-mouse/video
adSzLst:300x60,970x90,970x66,728x90
url:http://video.disney.com/watch/disneychannel-no-service-4df889ed3d82b43c9c01a272
urlDom:disney.com
urlFDom:video.disney.com
urlFDom1:video.disney.com/watch
refUrl:na
sessionData:no_dolWASessionData_cookie
visitorData:no_dolWAVisitorData_cookie
logStatus:lo|nr
prevPgNm:dcom|dch|watch:disneychannel-no-service-4df889ed3d82b43c9c01a272|disneychannel-no-service-4df889ed3d82b43c9c01a272
VIDLEN:210
GENTIME:1372188203486
GENTITLE:No Service | Mickey Mouse and Friends | Disney Video
GENURL:http://video.disney.com/watch/disneychannel-no-service-4df889ed3d82b43c9c01a272
DEVID:-1
USRAGNT:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
WIGID:1959
BITRATE:1000
KDPID:1959
mediaSumm:vid|dch|dmms|shr|0_y1nplyhi|No Service--**--210--**--dch--**--0--**--1372188203486--**--S0L0
accnt:disneyvideo2
brndSeg:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the last `<script>` tag, stored as JSON.

I don't work with Ruby, but here's how I would do it:

- Get the HTML of your page.
- Get the contents of the *last* `<script>` tag.
- The JSON is between two pieces of JavaScript:

  - Remove `this.Grill?Grill.burger=` from the beginning.
  - Remove `:(function(){var a=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];a.setAttribute("class",a.getAttribute("class")+" grill-error")})()` from the end.
- Parse the JSON and you've got all of the URLs.

Comment: Thank you! So it isn't shown in the inspector? how can I typically recognize the JSON? and how would I know the domain 'http://cdn.videos.dolimg.com/' if no other examples were given? I'm seeing if vimeo follows a similar pattern, but no such luck so far.

Comment: @user1297102: There's no foolproof way to do it. Just look for video file URLs in the source. If you can't find them, open up Wireshark and look for HTTP GET requests that return a video mimetype.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and for the help. Never used Wireshark, but it's probably better than only using the browsers inspector.

Comment: @user1297102: It's a different tool. Use the browser's inspector first and look through all of the source files and all of the scripts. If you can't find any, use Wireshark and look for a GET request that is responded to with a video mimetype. It's really just guessing.